# How to use properties of a Component in vue.js when input text changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using `Vuesax Framework Components` which it's working fine, but my in learning process for both `laravel/vue.js` and got a problem about how to use properties of component when input text got changed?

Consider this :

```
<vs-input
         style="width:100%"
         label="Label"
         danger-text="character"
         v-model="form.invoice_title"
         name="invoice_title"/>
```

in top code component gonna show me a input text with a red color with text which will tell use what is wrong, but in right idea i should make that red color show when something is wrong with inputs, like `input must be more than 3 Characters'.
[Input Component in vuesax](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/input.html)

So here's what i wanna do make my input activate/trigger `:danger & danger-text` properties when something is wrong Like:

inputs must be more than 6 and less than 80 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via a computed property. eg:

```
<vs-input
     style="width:100%"
     label="Label"
     :danger="hasError"
     :danger-text="errorText"
     v-model="form.invoice_title"
     name="invoice_title"/>

... // in javascript

computed() {
    hasError() {
        return this.form.invoice_title.length < 6 || this.form.invoice_title.length > 80
    }
    errorText() {
        if (this.form.invoice_title.length < 6) {
            return 'Invoice title should be at least 6 characters'
        }
        if (this.form.invoice_title.length > 80) {
            return 'Invoice title should be at most 80 characters'
        }
        return ''
    }
}
```

I highly recommend [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.netlify.com) lib form managing validation

Comment: hasError work but errorText won't work. computed method when inputs go wrong it just say errorText

Comment: note that I used a colon (`:`) that designates it's a bound property, alias to `v-bind:danger-text`. If you don't it will just use the variable you give it as text.